Is unauthorized for service account [elastic/fleet-server-remote] on restricted indices [.fleet-agents]
I have problems deploying the elastic-agent, currently my docker compose has two elasticsearch nodes, kibana and elastic-agent, the communication between elasticsearch and kibana works fine, but when connecting from the elastic-agent to the elasticsearch I have problems with error 403, within the elastic-stack services I have fleet server and apm with their agent policies, when loading kibana and entering fleet it does not load any agent, I have been reviewing this point for several weeks and I cannot solve it, in the end I am trying to enroll manually and I get the same error of 403, I share the log of the elastic-agent and the elasticsearch
It is worth mentioning that each service has its own DNS, I have the certificates signed to be used with https, it is the first time I do it this way, I have always tested on localhost and with http
I add the demo repository of my project: https://github.com/robertpablo/elastic-stack
#elastic-agent
{
    "log.level": "error",
    "@timestamp": "2024-08-21T16:18:04.033Z",
    "log.origin": {
        "file.name": "coordinator/coordinator.go",
        "file.line": 624
    },
    "message": "Unit state changed fleet-server-default (STARTING->FAILED): Error - failed to run subsystems: v7.15.0 data migration failed: failed to apply migration \"AgentMetadata\": migrate AgentMetadata UpdateByQuery failed: [403 Forbidden] {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"security_exception\",\"reason\":\"action [indices:data/write/update/byquery] is unauthorized for service account [elastic/fleet-server-remote] on restricted indices [.fleet-agents], this action is granted by the index privileges [index,write,all]\"}],\"type\":\"security_exception\",\"reason\":\"action [indices:data/write/update/byquery] is unauthorized for service account [elastic/fleet-server-remote] on restricted indices [.fleet-agents], this action is granted by the index privileges [index,write,all]\"},\"status\":403}",
    "log": {
        "source": "elastic-agent"
    },
    "component": {
        "id": "fleet-server-default",
        "state": "HEALTHY"
    },
    "unit": {
        "id": "fleet-server-default",
        "type": "output",
        "state": "FAILED",
        "old_state": "STARTING"
    },
    "ecs.version": "1.6.0"
}`

#elasticsearch.
{
    "@timestamp": "2024-08-21T16:19:00.846Z",
    "log.level": "DEBUG",
    "message": "path: /.fleet-agents/_update_by_query, params: {conflicts=proceed, refresh=true, index=.fleet-agents}, status: 403",
    "ecs.version": "1.2.0",
    "service.name": "ES_ECS",
    "event.dataset": "elasticsearch.server",
    "process.thread.name": "elasticsearch[ecp-elasticsearch1][transport_worker][T#5]",
    "log.logger": "rest.suppressed",
    "elasticsearch.cluster.uuid": "eoBaPNygR--zAr7bUjrmYg",
    "elasticsearch.node.id": "9h0CD68FTAO0XEgpB9mYAg",
    "elasticsearch.node.name": "ecp-elasticsearch1",
    "elasticsearch.cluster.name": "elastic-stack-project",
    "error.type": "org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException",
    "error.message": "action [indices:data/write/update/byquery] is unauthorized for service account [elastic/fleet-server-remote] on restricted indices [.fleet-agents], this action is granted by the index privileges [index,write,all]",
    "error.stack_trace": "org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException: action [indices:data/write/update/byquery] is unauthorized for service account [elastic/fleet-server-remote] on restricted indices [.fleet-agents], this action is granted by the index privileges [index,write,all]\n\tat org.elasticsearch.xcore@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.security.support.Exceptions.authorizationError(Exceptions.java:36)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.AuthorizationService.denialException(AuthorizationService.java:993)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.AuthorizationService.actionDenied(AuthorizationService.java:970)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.AuthorizationService$AuthorizationResultListener.handleFailure(AuthorizationService.java:1049)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.AuthorizationService$AuthorizationResultListener.onResponse(AuthorizationService.java:1035)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.AuthorizationService$AuthorizationResultListener.onResponse(AuthorizationService.java:996)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.action.support.ContextPreservingActionListener.onResponse(ContextPreservingActionListener.java:32)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.RBACEngine.lambda$authorizeIndexAction$3(RBACEngine.java:420)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerImplementations$ResponseWrappingActionListener.onResponse(ActionListenerImplementations.java:245)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.action.support.SubscribableListener$SuccessResult.complete(SubscribableListener.java:382)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.action.support.SubscribableListener.tryComplete(SubscribableListener.java:302)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.action.support.SubscribableListener.addListener(SubscribableListener.java:205)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.action.support.SubscribableListener.addListener(SubscribableListener.java:170)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.AuthorizationService$CachingAsyncSupplier.getAsync(AuthorizationService.java:1076)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.RBACEngine.authorizeIndexAction(RBACEngine.java:388)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.AuthorizationService.authorizeAction(AuthorizationService.java:507)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.AuthorizationService.maybeAuthorizeRunAs(AuthorizationService.java:439)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.AuthorizationService.lambda$authorize$3(AuthorizationService.java:326)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$2.onResponse(ActionListener.java:171)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.action.support.ContextPreservingActionListener.onResponse(ContextPreservingActionListener.java:32)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.RBACEngine.lambda$resolveAuthorizationInfo$0(RBACEngine.java:154)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerImplementations$ResponseWrappingActionListener.onResponse(ActionListenerImplementations.java:245)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.store.CompositeRolesStore.lambda$getRoles$4(CompositeRolesStore.java:193)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerImplementations$ResponseWrappingActionListener.onResponse(ActionListenerImplementations.java:245)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.store.CompositeRolesStore.lambda$getRole$5(CompositeRolesStore.java:211)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerImplementations$ResponseWrappingActionListener.onResponse(ActionListenerImplementations.java:245)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.xcore@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.security.authz.store.RoleReferenceIntersection.lambda$buildRole$0(RoleReferenceIntersection.java:49)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerImplementations$ResponseWrappingActionListener.onResponse(ActionListenerImplementations.java:245)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.action.support.GroupedActionListener.onResponse(GroupedActionListener.java:56)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.store.CompositeRolesStore.buildRoleFromRoleReference(CompositeRolesStore.java:291)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.xcore@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.security.authz.store.RoleReferenceIntersection.lambda$buildRole$1(RoleReferenceIntersection.java:53)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.xcore@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.security.authz.store.RoleReferenceIntersection.buildRole(RoleReferenceIntersection.java:53)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.store.CompositeRolesStore.getRole(CompositeRolesStore.java:209)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.store.CompositeRolesStore.getRoles(CompositeRolesStore.java:186)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.RBACEngine.resolveAuthorizationInfo(RBACEngine.java:150)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authz.AuthorizationService.authorize(AuthorizationService.java:342)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.action.filter.SecurityActionFilter.lambda$applyInternal$5(SecurityActionFilter.java:178)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerImplementations$ResponseWrappingActionListener.onResponse(ActionListenerImplementations.java:245)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerImplementations$MappedActionListener.onResponse(ActionListenerImplementations.java:95)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticatorChain.authenticate(AuthenticatorChain.java:93)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService.authenticate(AuthenticationService.java:264)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService.authenticate(AuthenticationService.java:173)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.action.filter.SecurityActionFilter.applyInternal(SecurityActionFilter.java:174)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.action.filter.SecurityActionFilter.apply(SecurityActionFilter.java:131)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:93)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:68)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.tasks.TaskManager.registerAndExecute(TaskManager.java:196)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.client.internal.node.NodeClient.executeLocally(NodeClient.java:105)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.reindex.AbstractBaseReindexRestHandler.lambda$doPrepareRequest$0(AbstractBaseReindexRestHandler.java:52)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler.handleRequest(BaseRestHandler.java:106)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController$1.onResponse(RestController.java:452)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController$1.onResponse(RestController.java:446)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.rest.SecurityRestFilter.doHandleRequest(SecurityRestFilter.java:89)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.rest.SecurityRestFilter.lambda$intercept$0(SecurityRestFilter.java:81)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$2.onResponse(ActionListener.java:171)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.support.SecondaryAuthenticator.lambda$authenticateAndAttachToContext$3(SecondaryAuthenticator.java:99)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerImplementations$ResponseWrappingActionListener.onResponse(ActionListenerImplementations.java:245)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.support.SecondaryAuthenticator.authenticate(SecondaryAuthenticator.java:109)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.support.SecondaryAuthenticator.authenticateAndAttachToContext(SecondaryAuthenticator.java:90)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.security@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.rest.SecurityRestFilter.intercept(SecurityRestFilter.java:75)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:446)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.tryAllHandlers(RestController.java:606)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:329)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.http.AbstractHttpServerTransport.dispatchRequest(AbstractHttpServerTransport.java:487)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.http.AbstractHttpServerTransport.handleIncomingRequest(AbstractHttpServerTransport.java:583)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.http.AbstractHttpServerTransport.incomingRequest(AbstractHttpServerTransport.java:460)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpPipeliningHandler.handlePipelinedRequest(Netty4HttpPipeliningHandler.java:126)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpPipeliningHandler.channelRead(Netty4HttpPipeliningHandler.java:116)\n\tat io.netty.transport@4.1.107.Final/io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)\n\tat io.netty.transport@4.1.107.Final/io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)\n\tat io.netty.transport@4.1.107.Final/io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)\n\tat io.netty.codec@4.1.107.Final/io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)\n\tat io.netty.transport@4.1.107.Final/io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)\n\tat io.netty.transport@4.1.107.Final/io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)\n\tat io.netty.transport@4.1.107.Final/io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)\n\tat io.netty.codec@4.1.107.Final/io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)\n\tat io.netty.transport@4.1.107.Final/io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)\n\tat io.netty.transport@4.1.107.Final/io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)\n\tat io.netty.transport@4.1.107.Final/io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpHeaderValidator.forwardData(Netty4HttpHeaderValidator.java:209)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpHeaderValidator.forwardFullRequest(Netty4HttpHeaderValidator.java:152)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4@8.14.1/org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpHeaderValidator$1.lambda$onResponse$0(Netty4HttpHeaderValidator.java:125)\n\tat io.netty.common@4.1.107.Final/io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:173)\n\tat io.netty.common@4.1.107.Final/io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:166)\n\tat io.netty.common@4.1.107.Final/io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)\n\tat io.netty.transport@4.1.107.Final/io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:566)\n\tat io.netty.common@4.1.107.Final/io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)\n\tat io.netty.common@4.1.107.Final/io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)\n"
}

be able to resolve the communication between elastic-agent and elasticsearch
